# Dual Flush Conversion not sealing anymore

Tags: plumbing, toilet

About a year ago we bought a dual flush conversion kit for the very old and very high-capacity toilet in the house we just purchased. I don't remember the exact model, but I believe it either was this one or something *very similar*:

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Unbranded-HydroKit-Toilet-Repair-with-Dual-Flush-Converter-HYR451T/202762847

[image]

Now, it worked fine for about a year (although I was a little disappointed that it wouldn't always flush away toilet paper with the small flush), but now it seems like it's leaking slowing into the bowl causing the valve to periodically open refill the tank. Obviously this kills the whole point of saving water with the dual flush.

I *think* the problem is with the blue rubber gasket. You are supposed to just push it over the opening to the tank and it's supposed to just seat itself. It was doing that for a while, but now as much as I've tried jingling it and reseating it, it's still letting water drain into the bowl. I couldn't see any visible damage to the rubber, so I'm guess it's just lost some elasticity.

Short of buying a new dual flush kit (which I'm not keen on doing if they will only last a year) or going back to a regular flap value and giving up hope of saving water or getting a brand new modern toilet (which we might do eventually, but isn't something I'm comfortable doing myself), does anybody have any experience or ideas for making this seat more reliably? I thought maybe some type of silicon sealant of something, but obviously I don't want to glue it in to the extent that I can't get it out again if I need to.

Comment: IIRC this is a common problem with this kit, as seen in the Amazon reviews. Some claim to have had success by removing the (possibly already broken - many said it broke in 6 months or less) - must be low quality) zip tie that's supposed to keep the thing positioned on the tube and using a stainless steel hose clamp instead. I don't have one (the reviews put me off) but that was my sense after reading through them - the hose clamp might let you put more reliable down pressure on the gasket and help the seal.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: I did replace the tie anyway since I had to cut it off to remove it before I could inspect it and try to reseat. Maybe I should try to push it down harder and tighten it up. The collar that goes around the tube never felt like a very good fit. A stainless steel clamp might be a good suggestion, thanks.

Comment: BTW, once you get past the "eww, but it's the stinky pipe" factor, replacing a toilet is actually fairly easy, unless you find terrible problems under it (and they would raise the cost and time if you had a plumber doing it, too.) ••• You could try silicone grease on the seal - it may help the seal, but being grease, not caulk, it won't make things *stick* (though it can be godawfully *sticky*, especially if you find my favorite version, vacuum grease.)